# Why do not all the semimetals turn into the excitonic insulators?

Tags: solid-state-physics, phase-transition, electronic-band-theory, metals, insulators

I want to know the condition for forming the excitonic insulator.

When the binding energy of the exciton, $E_b$, overcomes the band gap, the system becomes the excitonic insulator. If so, all semimetals should meet this condition and be supposed to turn into excitonic insulators, like 1T-TiSe2.
Why isn't it thought so? Is there what I must take into account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the binding energy of the exciton, Eb, overcomes the band gap, the system becomes the excitonic insulator.

What is meant here is the *direct gap*, i.e., the gap between the conduction and valence band states located at the same point of the Brillouin zone (having the same quasi-momentum). On the other hand, in most semimetals the band overlap happens for the states having very different quasi-momenta (se image below, [image source is here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimetal#Schematic)) - that is, the gap for the electron and the hole bound into an exciton might be still bigger than the binding energy.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But you mean that the quasi-momenta are so small that the electron and the hole can bound each other, in the case of TiSe2?

Comment: @Kaido If we consider exciton as a hydrogen-like bound state of an electron and a hole, and take its wave function in k-space, it will have some width. If electron and hole are too far apart in momentum space (provided their total momentum is close to zero) they will not bind, just as if they were too far apart in the real space.

Comment: I could understand what is important in thinking about exciton formation. I appreciate your comment.